# Maximum size of vertex set with no induced connected component on more than k vertices

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, terminology

An **independent set** of a graph is a collection of vertices such that the induced subgraph consists of disconnected vertices.  The maximum possible cardinality of an independent set is then called the **independence number** of the graph.

For $k$ a positive integer, we define a **$k$-independent set** of a graph to be a collection of vertices such that the induced subgraph consists of components with $k$ vertices or fewer. (In particular, a $1$-independent set is the same as an independent set.)  We then define the **$k$-independence number** of a graph to be the maximum possible cardinality of a $k$-independent set.

Have these notions of $k$-independent sets and $k$-independence numbers been studied before?  If so, what names do they go by in the literature?

(Note:  the term "$k$-independence number" does appear in the literature, but it asks for the induced subgraphs to have maximum degree at most $k$, rather than at most $k$ vertices.)

Answer (score 1):

There is a version of graph colouring where instead of insisting that each colour class is an independent set, you require each colour class to be a $c$-independent set.  This is known as a colouring with *clustering* $c$.  The *clustered chromatic number* of a class of graphs is the minimum $k$ such that for some integer $c$, every graph in the class is $k$-colourable with clustering $c$.  Clustered chromatic number has received quite a lot of attention recently.  For example, van den Heuvel and Wood proved that every $K_t$-minor free graph is $(2t-2)$-colourable with clustering at most $\lceil\frac{1}{2}(t-2) \rceil$.  Note that the analogous statement for the chromatic number is the *linear Hadwidger's conjecture*, and is still open.

See this [survey](https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.07694) by David Wood for more information. The survey also discusses colourings where each colour class has bounded maximum degree.  These are known as *defective colourings*.